# [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded

Tags: vue.js, quasar, store

Buenas me sale el siguiente warning el cual provoca que cuando abro esta ruta el componente tarda en cargar y luego se queda bugeado el menu. *[Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.* Lo que sospecho es que puede ser por que almacenos los datos en una variable de store:

Aqui el codigo del front en el cual llamo a la store y pinto una grafica de rangeBar:

```
<script setup>
  import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
  import { useAdquisicion } from "../stores/main";
  import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
  
  const adquisicionStore = useAdquisicion();
  
  const chartSeries = ref([
    {
      name: 'horno1',
      data: [],
    }
  ]);
  
  const chartOptions = {
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: true,
        barHeight: '20%'
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 1
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'solid',
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
  };  
  
  onMounted(async () => {
    await adquisicionStore.loadHornoMarcha();
    updateChartSeries();
  });
  
  const updateChartSeries = () => {
    // Make sure adquisicionStore.hornoMarcha is an array of data
    chartSeries.value[0].data = adquisicionStore.hornoMarcha;
  }
  </script>
```

Y este es la store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAdquisicion = defineStore('adquisicion', {
  state: () => ({
    hornoMarcha: [],
    loading: true
  }),

  actions: {

      async loadHornoMarcha() {
        try {
          const responseHorMar = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/horno-marcha');
          if (responseHorMar.status === 200) {
            this.hornoMarcha = responseHorMar.data;
            this.loading = false;
          } else {
            console.error('Error al obtener datos: Respuesta no válida');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error);
        }
      },

  },
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error viene del plugin apexcharts y como manejas los arrays ya que los pasa como reactivos y eso provoca el error. La solución a eso fue agregar toRaw a :series para quitarles la reactividad a la array.

```
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div class="q-pa-md">
      <VueApexCharts
        type="rangeBar"
        :height="200"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :series="toRaw(chartSeries)"
      />
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue3-apexcharts';
import { useAdquisicion } from "../stores/example-store";
import { ref, onMounted, toRaw } from "vue";

const adquisicionStore = useAdquisicion();

const chartSeries = ref([]); // Ahora es un array vacío para los datos

const chartOptions = {
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: true,
        barHeight: '20%'
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 1
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'solid',
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
  };

const fetchHornoMarcha = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await adquisicionStore.loadHornoMarcha();
    console.log
    // Asigna los datos a chartSeries
    chartSeries.value = [{
      data: response
    }];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al cargar datos:", error);
  }
};

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetchHornoMarcha();
});

</script>

<style scoped>
#time-chart {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```